# Connect to container outside gitlab-runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

My project (stored on GitLab) interacts with the Gitlab API. I would like to automate the test that validates that this interaction works using a CI/CD pipeline.

My first thought was to use `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest` as a `service`, but that does not work for me, since launching this `gitlab-ce` server is really slow. Instead, I'm aiming to host a local instance of `gitlab-ce` that persists between CI/CD executions (on the same server as the one hosting the gitlab-runner). Then my project can connect to that local instance when it is being tested.

I have one server, which now hosts a copy of `gitlab/gitlab-ce`, with the following dockerfile:

**gitlab/gitlab-ce dockerfile**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    environment:
      - GITLAB_HOME='/srv/gitlab'
      - GITLAB_HTTPS="false"
      - GITLAB_ROOT_PASSWORD="********"  
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:8080:80'
      - '127.0.0.1:4443:443'
      - '127.0.0.1:2222:22'
    volumes:
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOM
```

I am attempting to reach this instance from the runner (hosted on the same server) executing the CI/CD pipeline. The `.gitlab-ci.yml` I'm using in current testing is as follows:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - test

services:
  - host: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    alias: gitlab

test:py310:
  script:
    - curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${GITLAB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}" http://localhost:8080/api/v4/users
```

The output of the pipeline is as follows:

**Execution output**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.5.1 (7178588d)
  on **** -****
Preparing the "docker" executor 00:02
Using Docker executor with image python:3.10 ...
Pulling docker image python:3.10 ...
Using docker image sha256:**** for python:3.10 with digest python@sha256:**** ...
Preparing environment 00:00
Running on runner--****-project-4324-concurrent-0 via ****...
Getting source from Git repository 00:02
Fetching changes...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/****/.git/
<removed some lines>
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:00
Using docker image sha256:**** for python:3.10 with digest python@sha256:**** ...
$ curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${GITLAB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}" http://localhost:8080/api/v4/users
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

For reference, this is the output of `docker inspect gitlab-runner`.
Here, long hashes, passwords and identifying information has been replaced with `****`

**gitlab-runner `docker inspect` output**

```
[
    {
        "Id": "****",
        "Created": "2022-11-14T13:32:07.031778134Z",
        "Path": "/usr/bin/dumb-init",
        "Args": [
            "/entrypoint",
            "run",
            "--user=gitlab-runner",
            "--working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 1392,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-06-01T07:20:09.623373469Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2023-06-01T05:46:58.825527274Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:****",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/****/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/****/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/****/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/****/****-json.log",
        "Name": "/gitlab-runner",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "gitlab-runner-config:/etc/gitlab-runner",
                "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/****/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/****/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/****/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/****/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/****/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/****/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/****/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "gitlab-runner-config",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/gitlab-runner-config/_data",
                "Destination": "/etc/gitlab-runner",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "****",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/****/_data",
                "Destination": "/home/gitlab-runner",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                "Destination": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "****",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "run",
                "--user=gitlab-runner",
                "--working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner"
            ],
            "Image": "gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest",
            "Volumes": {
                "/etc/gitlab-runner": {},
                "/home/gitlab-runner": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/usr/bin/dumb-init",
                "/entrypoint"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {},
            "StopSignal": "SIGQUIT"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "****",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/b7fd8cb50750",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "****",
            "Gateway": "****",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "****",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "****",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "****",
                    "EndpointID": "****",
                    "Gateway": "****",
                    "IPAddress": "****",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "****",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```